# Difference between machine/processor/hardware-platform

Tags: linux, unix, coreutils

In using the `uname` command the following three options gives me the same output:

```sh
ubuntu@ip-172:~/asm/asm$ uname -p
# x86_64
ubuntu@ip-172:~/asm/asm$ uname -i
# x86_64
ubuntu@ip-172:~/asm/asm$ uname -m
x86_64
```

Are the `-m`, `-i`, and `-p` options essentially the same thing, are what is the difference between them? From the man:

> `-m`, --machine
>
> `-p`, --processor
> print the processor type (non-portable)
>
> `-i`, --hardware-platform
> print the hardware platform (non-portable)